# ffmpeg webcam capture a/v out of sync

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running this command to capture video and audio from my webcam:

```
ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0" -ac 2 -strict experimental Filename.mp4
```

It works, but the audio is about half a second behind the video (EG if I clap, when I watch the video I'll hear the clap and then see me do it).

This is for an online stream, so I can't fix it up later, it needs to be recorded correctly.

It always seems to be off by the same amount, so I'm trying to find an option to simply delay when audio starts recording, but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you give google a try? Look [here](http://lzone.de/fix%20async%20video%20with%20ffmpeg)
They suggest to use `-async` or `-vsync` depending on your requirement, or `-map` in combination with `-itsoffset`

Using a recent `ffmpeg` with the following command should do the work:

```
ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -itsoffset 2 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0" -ac 2 -strict experimental Filename.mp4
```

Comment: async and vsync don't work, and I think the solution using map and itsoffset only works if you have source files on your hard disk. In my case it is coming directly from the webcam.

Comment: The results google cam up with suggest itsoffset should work with streams coming from your webcam, too. Try `ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -itsoffset 00:00.5 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0" -ac 2 -strict experimental Filename.mp4`. Does it give any errors or just no different result?

Comment: No errors, the result is the same.

Comment: What version of ffmpeg are you using? Can you try capturing a few seconds of both input streams to a file and running the command on them and see if it works then?

Comment: 0.8.12-6:0.8.12-1 I don't think itsoffset is the solution anyway. Using itfoffset I can make the video stream start LATER (IE still frames at the beginning), with a +ve itsoffset but that's no good since the audio is playing too early. And if I use a negative offset it just doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: `-itsoffset` should also be able to delay the audio stream. Put it behind the -i of your audio and try again. Also note that in your question you said the audio was behind. If it still doesn't work you may be able to add the delay with a alsa softdevice.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference where I put the itsoffset.

Comment: I would try getting a more recent version of ffmpeg, the old versions are known to have bugs with itsoffset. Also please try if it works with recorded streams. Or give the ALSA approach a try.

Comment: Can you point me to some resources on Alsa softdevices. I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Compiling 1.0.9 and using ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -itsoffset 2 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0" -ac 2 -strict experimental Filename.mp4 worked. So if you post that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: > "Did you give google a try?"

This was the top result on Google for me.

Answer (score 1):

See [FFmpeg: audio start time way off](https://superuser.com/questions/1584945/ffmpeg-audio-start-time-way-off) how I solved a very similar problem. I used to use `-itsoffset` before, but it is too much guesswork for my taste.