# FFmpeg: audio start time way off

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, timestamp

Real-time audio and video is recorded from one audio source and two video sources:

```
ffmpeg -y -copyts \
  -f pulse -thread_queue_size 1024 -i alsa_input.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i2_USB_Y8CAJW2063E5BD-00.analog-stereo \
  -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 \
  -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video6 \
  -map 0:a -map 1:v -map 2:v -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast test.mp4
```

The `-copyts` effects a synchronization of the two video streams (see also [FFmpeg: synchronize streams from two webcams](https://superuser.com/q/1584557/494683)). But there is no audio to be heard on the recording. Looking at the start times in the output explains why:

```
Input #0, pulse, from 'alsa_input.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i2_USB_Y8CAJW2063E5BD-00.analog-stereo':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1599927759.812456, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 54432.851793, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Input #2, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video6':
  Duration: N/A, start: 54433.882342, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
```

The two times from the video devices are close together, as expected: 54432.851793 and 54433.882342. But that from the audio device is way off: 1599927759.812456.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The time provided by the audio device actually is the saner one: it appears to be the time since the Epoch. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266451/where-does-v4l2-buffer-timestamp-value-starts-counting for more on this. This also indicates a way to fix this: `-af "asetpts=PTS-x/TB"`, where `x` is the time in seconds when the system was booted (*not* the uptime, but the point in time when the system was booted). You can get it from `/proc/stats`, the line starting with `btime`. It appears that this can be messed up when the system goes to suspend or similar, so pay attention to this.

The use of `asetpts` and `setpts` can also get rid of the second pass with `-start_at_zero`, which was suggested in [FFmpeg: synchronize streams from two webcams](https://superuser.com/q/1584557/494683). Here is a full example solution:

```
btime_=`grep btime /proc/stat | awk '{print $2}'`
utime_=`awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime`
btime_utime_=`echo "${btime_?} + ${utime_?}" | bc -l`
ffmpeg -y -copyts \
  -f pulse -thread_queue_size 1024 -i alsa_input.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i2_USB_Y8CAJW2063E5BD-00.analog-stereo \
  -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 \
  -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video6 \
  -map 0:a -map 1:v -map 2:v -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
  -af "asetpts=PTS-${btime_utime_?}/TB" \
  -vf "setpts=PTS-${utime_?}/TB" \
  test.mp4
```

Note that shifting by the uptime (in order to avoid the second pass with `-start_at_zero`) is not totally exact in that the first PTS will be slightly more than zero. But it is good enough for my purposes so far.